# experimental procedure regarding AceCS1 overexpression

Tags: experiment, fatty-acid-synthase

I'm new to biology and was just as to curious on how one can experimentally prove/disprove that AceCS1 overexpression in mammalian cells would yield enhanced rates of fatty acid synthesis through acetate.

Thanks.